# Load every objects saved as json

Tags: android, json

*I'm saving my playlists as json file, but oncreate I want to load every playlist already saved.*

This is my save function;

```
void Kaydet(PLAYLIST liste_mp3)
{

    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(liste_mp3);
    prefsEditor.putString(liste_mp3.ad, json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

*And this is PLAYLIST class,*

```
public class PLAYLIST
    {
        public String ad;
        public ArrayList<MP3> liste;

        public PLAYLIST(String ad1,ArrayList<MP3> liste1)
        {
            ad = ad1;
            liste = liste1;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return ad;
        }
        public ArrayList<MP3> LISTE()
        {
            return liste;
        }
    }
```

*This where I load specific one;*

```
if(Yukle("A liste") != null) {
        playlist.add(Yukle("A liste"));
    } else { playlist.add(new PLAYLIST("A liste",a_liste)); }
```

*and this is Load function,*

```
PLAYLIST Yukle(String playlist_name)
{
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = appSharedPrefs.getString(playlist_name, "");
    PLAYLIST p = gson.fromJson(json, PLAYLIST.class);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with that idea, I created a new function that saves names of all playlists as string arraylist, and load string arraylist of playlists' names then make a for-loop and load per playlist with name.

This is in onCreate()

```
ArrayList<String> yukleniyor = YukleHepsi();
        if(yukleniyor != null) {
            for (String isimler : yukleniyor) {
               playlist.add(Yukle(isimler));
            }
        }
```

This function loads names:

```
ArrayList<String> YukleHepsi()
    {
        SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = appSharedPrefs.getString("isimler", "");
        ArrayList<String> p = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
        return p;
    }
```

And this function saves the names of all playlits,

```
void KaydetHepsi()
    {
        ArrayList<String> isimler = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(PLAYLIST p: playlist)
        {
            if(p.ad != "None") {
                isimler.add(p.ad);
            }
        }
        SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(isimler);
        prefsEditor.putString("isimler", json);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: You should accept this answer so it doesn't show as an unanswered question.

Comment: I can't accept because it has been more than 9 hours :(

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't the other way around - you were trying accept the answer too soon?  Seems very strange to not allow you to accept after a few hours has passed.